# What part could I use for this battery terminal?

Tags: suzuki, atv

This Suzuki ATV battery requires a special kind of right angle terminal attached to the battery.  Items 2 and 3 in the figure:
[image: suzuki battery]

Here's a close up of what one looks like:
[image: battery terminal]

I don't have the terminals and one terminal costs $3, plus shipping. I really don't want to pay over $12 for two of these little things.

I could swap out the battery but I just bought it and it's brand new.

I thought about bending the ring connectors on the existing wires but that would probably break them, and it would be difficult (if not impossible) to get a tight fit on the terminal.

Is there a cheaper alternative I could replace the terminals with?

Comment: There are some batteries available that have the flexibility built into the battery terminal already, see https://www.batteryupgrade.ch/shopBrowser.php?assortmentProductId=40248599&shopGroupId=88938317&tracker=adwordsk_ch_fr_GP-pla_Motorcycle&gdataKwd=&gdataType=pla&gclid=CjwKCAjw7anqBRALEiwAgvGgmxocfitLYjWsbNmmaZNDOZvkPEDwHDJmR6zDQ1lrHJrwXyXHvKNS7xoCbNIQAvD_BwE

Comment: You could get a piece of copper and cut and bend it to the correct shape.

Answer (score 1):

Bending terminals is a possibility - did that often in the past but it is dodgy with the cheap ones, they can fracture then break easily.

Those terminals are probably used because the access is so poor that it may be almost impossible to do up the bolts on the standard battery terminals when it is in place...

I would look at extending the wires, but then you have to be able to store them safely...